# Is StreamBuilder Snapshot is empty

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

```
StreamBuilder(
        stream: firestore
            .collection('Product')
            .doc(order.productId)
            .collection('AbleToReview')
            .doc(auth.currentUser.uid)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Something went wrong');
          }

          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }

          if (snapshot.data==null){
            return Text('no data');
          } else {
            return Text('have data');
          }
        }
    )
```

Some time no data exist in *firestore.collection('Product').doc(order.productId).collection('AbleToReview').doc(auth.currentUser.uid).snapshots()* query. As depend on data exist or not I try to retue diffrent widget. But `snapshot.data==null` or `!snapshot.hasData` not the correct way thats I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the actual data from the query is empty using `snapshot.data.documents.isEmpty()`.

You can update your code to the one below:

```dart
    if (snapshot.data==null || snapshot.data.data().isEmpty()){
        return Text('no data');
    } else {
        return Text('have data');
    }
```

Comment: Class 'DocumentSnapshot' has no instance getter 'documents'.
Receiver: Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot'
Tried calling: documents

Comment: @HasanToufiqAhamed, it should be `.data()` not `.documents`. Please check out the updated answer.